# How define textarea content on form edit (Symfony2/TWIG)

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, textarea

I want to display a specific content in my editForm textarea so I try like text field but it doesn't work :

```
{{ form_widget(edit_form.description, { 'attr': {'value': 'content'} }) }} {{ form_errors(edit_form.description) }}
```

How can I do it in TWIG ?

Comment: do you have to do it in twig? or you are open to defining the value in form class it self for textarea?

Comment: you can use option 'data' in formbuilder too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work according to [the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#twig-reference-form-variables).

```
{{ form_widget(edit_form.description, { 'value': 'content'}) }} {{ form_errors(edit_form.description) }}
```

But I've never tested it.

Comment: That's it thank you! the 'value' attribute must not be in the 'attr'.

Comment: still relevant for Symfony 4.0

Comment: still works on Symfony 5.4... additionally, you can use either of form_row or form_widget tags and they will both work.